# Question on PHP Regex 

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP regex, and I read the http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. but can't find the way to fix my bug.
Could you please give me a hand? 
Thanks.

```
<?php

$myURL = "/something/";  
// If myURL include two or more than two '/' then return Found, Else return Not found two '/'

if (preg_match("/\/?\//", $myURL)) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$myURL = "/something/";  
// If myURL include two or more than two '/' then return Found, Else return Not found two '/'

if (preg_match("/\/.*\//", $myURL)) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's cool, I prefer to Regex solution.

Comment: As you wish, but Regex is overkill for this kind of action.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using [substr_count](http://il2.php.net/substr_count).

```php
$numSlashes = substr_count($text, '/');
```

Shai.

Comment: I'd go with this, but it you want to use regular expressions it would be easier to use different delimiters: `$regex = "#/.*/#";`

Comment: +1. I still need to seek and read PHP manual carefully. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go by regex way then:

```
$myURL = "/some//thing/";  


if (array_search("//", preg_match_all("/\/?\//", $myURL))) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
?>
```